# Cross domain issue in Google API's using angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-domain

I am using following code to get the location details from the google API.

My code :

```
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude+'&sensor=true').then(function(res){
          alert(res.data);
        });


      });
    });
  }
```

When I try this code I am getting the Cross domain Error.

My Error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=8.5663029,76.8916023&sensor=true. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Please suggest to solve this issue

Comment: You have to add authorization header first. your request should be `$http.jsonp` or do `method: 'JSONP'`

Comment: `Request header field Authorization is not allowed` - the problem could be that ?something? is adding a request header `Authorization` ... google doesn't like that, it seems ... CORS is not usually an issue with that API call

Comment: @ParthTrivedi `You have to add authorization header first` ... the problem is the existence of the Authorization header!! not the lack of it

Answer (score 2):

You're sending an Authorization header ... which causes a CORS preflight check, and google doesn't like the Authorization header

you need to remove this header from the API call

see if this helps

```
$http.get("your long url", {headers: {Authorization: undefined}})
```

obviously I've replaced the actual url for readability

I've also seen the following suggestion

```
$http( {
     method: 'GET',
     url: 'someurl',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': undefined
     }
   }
 )
```

so, rather than using the $http.get "shortcut", use $http "general" request format

Comment: oh it seems problem with this. hmm

Comment: @ParthTrivedi - what are you trying to say? I don't understand, sorry

Comment: you are right.problem with passing header that is not mentioned in OP's code.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi `that is not mentioned` - it is mentioned in the CORS error message, that's how I know which one to remove :p

Comment: To solve the cross domain issue do we need to pass headers: {Authorization: null} ?

Comment: @Kichu read the error you are getting ... google doesn't like getting an Authorization header ... after briefly reading angular documentation (I've never used angular, ever) it appears that passing in a header set to null will REMOVE the header from the request ... WHY the header is being sent in the first place, I have no idea. All I do know is that API works just fine from my domain, but my request does NOT send an Authorization header

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not expert in this type of things. Can you please tell what is authorization header? How can i remove from my request . i used {headers: {Authorization: null}}. But still getting the same error..

Comment: I do not know why your request is sending Authorization header ... clearly I misunderstood the angular documentation, it implied that setting a header to null in the options of the .get would remove the header from the request

Comment: Then what is the solution. Can you please suggest?

Comment: @Kichu I've added an alternative - also, make sure the error is still complaining about `Authorization` header, it may be a different header? possibly?

Comment: @Kichu first, try `undefined` instead of `null` ... just re-read the angular documentation :p

Comment: still complaining about `Authorization` header? angular documentation isn't very helpful in that case

Comment: just for laughs, try a different browser

Comment: Still I am in same issue. Do we need to change any server config to allow crossorgin request?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue; I was using the satellizer module for authentication.
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

As it says on the FAQ section:
"How can I avoid sending Authorization header on all HTTP requests?"

I did:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'your google api URL',
  skipAuthorization: true  // `Authorization: Bearer <token>` will not be sent on this request.
});
```

And it solved my problem; maybe you are using a third party module that modifies the header.

Answer (score -1):

I can't answer in the threat of the response i want, but

Maybe your are using Interceptors in your AngularJS application, so your request is modified some time later after your configure the:

```
{headers: { Authorization: null } }
```

I'm doing more research to overcome this. I'll post my finds later.

**[Edit] Wed Jul 13 2016 21:38:03 GMT-0500 (CDT) [/Edit]**

My solution to this, is going with straight Javascript, in that way my petition does not is intercepted by Interceptors from the $http Service and does not have the Authorization header.

So, maybe this help someone.

Cheers!